# numpy.genfromtxt parsing column names with escape characters incorrectly

Tags: python, string, csv, escaping, genfromtxt

I am reading large amounts of data from a CSV file with the following code

```
data = np.genfromtxt(inputfile.name, delimiter=',', dtype=float, names=True)
```

According to the docstring, using the names Keyword with the True value, implies that the data is structured in a 1d structured array where the columns of the original CSV file are accessible via their names, taken from the first row of the file.

While this works in general, it seems that the name strings are not parsed as I would expect as raw strings. r'some string'

e.g. the string from the file

```
s = "LNAGain(Corner=nom_8;modelFiles=model.paths.scs;cur_ctl_counter=1;vsupply=1.65;temperature=85) Y"
#correct
```

gets parsed as

```
s="LNAGain_Cornernom_8modelFilesmodelpathsscscur_ctl_counter1vsupply165temperature85_Y"
#wrong
```

So it misses the equal signs, semicolons and parenthesis.
Is there a way to force the reading as raw string ? Or is this a bug in the numpy method?

If I just read the line with

```
inputfile.readline()
```

everything is parsed correctly/as I want.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got around my issue by using the pandas module for the csv import, instead of numpy. See http://pandas.pydata.org

It seems to parse the text-file containing the data in a much smarter way.

So, instead of doing

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(inputfile.name, delimiter=',', dtype=float, names=True)
```

I do

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(inputfile.name, sep=',')
```

and all is fine. :)

Of course I had to edit my code to use the pandas methods for handling the data-object, but changes where minor.

e.g. to access a data column I would use

```
data[data.columns[column_index]]
```

instead of

```
data[data.dtype.names[column_index]
```